# iTextSharp System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itext

I am trying to make a method to get the PDF bytes:

```
public static Byte[] HtmlToBytes(string htmlText)
    {
        Byte[] bytes;

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 10, 10))
            {
                using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms))
                {
                    writer.CloseStream = false;
                    doc.Open();
                    using (var msHtml = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(htmlText)))
                    {
                        XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, msHtml, Encoding.UTF8);
                    }
                }
            }
            bytes = ms.ToArray();
        }

        return bytes;
    }
```

But it gives out a NullReferenceException at this part

```
XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, msHtml, Encoding.UTF8);
```

On the string I am passing there is only plain html like a table and a  tag.

Here`s the Stack Trace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
iTextSharp.tool.xml.pipeline.html.HtmlPipeline.Close(IWorkerContext context, Tag t, ProcessObject po) +76
iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorker.EndElement(String tag, String ns) +186
iTextSharp.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.EndElement() +111
iTextSharp.tool.xml.parser.state.ClosingTagState.Process(Char character) +61
iTextSharp.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.ParseWithReader(TextReader reader) +247
iTextSharp.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.Parse(TextReader reader) +5
iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.ParseXHtml(PdfWriter writer, Document doc, TextReader inp) +453
TCC.Globals.HtmlToBytes(String htmlText) in C:\Users\Felipe\Source\Workspaces\Workspace\SgLeitos\TCC\TCC\Helpers\Globals.cs:118
TCC.Controllers.RelatoriosController.Leitos(Nullable`1 id) in C:\Users\Felipe\Source\Workspaces\Workspace\SgLeitos\TCC\TCC\Controllers\RelatoriosController.cs:34
lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +107
System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157 ...
```

Comment: If you hit the break point on the XMLWorkerHelper, has the msHtml variable in fact been instanciated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried as fallows:

```
public static Byte[] HtmlToBytes(string htmlText)
    {
        Byte[] bytes;

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 10, 10))
            {
                using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms))
                {
                    writer.CloseStream = false;
                    doc.Open();
                    using (var msHtml = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(htmlText)))
                    {
                        XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, msHtml, Encoding.UTF8);
                    }
                }
            }
            bytes = ms.ToArray();
        }

        return bytes;
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var str = @"<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=""en"" xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml""><head><meta charset=""utf-8"" /><title></title></head><body><table border=""1"" style=""width:100%""><tr><td>Jill</td><td>Smith</td><td>50</td></tr><tr><td>Eve</td><td>Jackson</td><td>94</td></tr></table></body></html>";
        var s = HtmlToBytes(str);
        var str2 = @"<table border=""1"" style=""width:100%""><tr><td>Jill</td><td>Smith</td><td>50</td></tr><tr><td>Eve</td><td>Jackson</td><td>94</td></tr></table>";
        s = HtmlToBytes(str2);
        var str3 = @"<tabl=""width:100%""><tr><td>Jill</td><td>Smith</td><td>50</td></tr><tr><td>Eve</td><td>Jackson</td><td>94</td></tr></table>";
        s = HtmlToBytes(str3); //NULL HERE with corrupted html
    }
```

so the possible answere is, **your HTML is corrupted**

Comment: That was it. I found out that my html to string converter was also putting /r and /n, as well as the tabs from the file.

Comment: @FelipeDeguchi Likewise you could look at the way I've solved it. It was not that hard too test it that way youselft. I Imported nuget packages in seconds [tutorial](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-console), and checked 3 testcases without knowledge of librabries i've used in this examples (Itextsharp). I, ofcource, do not blame you, I was at your stage too when i have no idea how to solve problems like yours. But in the future best way to practice programming/solve is try alone. Also I recommend to read [What Have Your Tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/). GL :)